# Python 3.4 - Text.get() on Tkinter returns Attribute Error

Tags: tkinter, textbox

Im using Python3.4

I was trying to run a simple program that reads the Input from the Text Box Widget of Tkinter.

Im New to Tkinter, from the TkDocs i saw its a simple get command that would read the content of Text Box and store in a Variable.

In My case neither Insert nor Get is working; both of them gives as Unknown Attribute Get & Insert.

I was facing difficulty to add the code, please check the image[Containd the sample Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtX7z.jpg)

Comment: don't provide snapshot of code. We would appreciate copy pasting the code by editing in question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is because `text = Text().pack()` assigns to `text` value returned by `pack()` which always returns `None`. You have to do it in two lines.

```
text = Text(...) # create object and assing to variable
text.pack()      # put object in window
```

BTW: you can use `Text(...).pack()` when you don't have to assing object `Text` to variable.

Generally

```
variable = Widget(...)
variable.pack()         # or variable.grid(), variable.place()
```

or (when you don't need variable)

```
Widget(...).pack()      # or Widget(...).grid(), Widget(...).place()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = Text(//your  arguments)
text.pack()
```

Comment: Your answer is unclear. Whenever you provide code in an answer you should also provide a description. Otherwise the reader is left to guess what's special about your code, which may not be obvious to a beginner.